# how to return Enum object from the value provided

Tags: java, enums

I have an Enum as follows:

```
enum Mobile {
   Samsung(400), Nokia(250),Motorola(325);

   int price;
   Mobile(int p) {
      price = p;
   }
   int showPrice() {
      return price;
   } 
}
```

How do I get Enum object provided a value
e.g if input is 400 output should be Samsung Enum object.

Please suggest.

Comment: Well, you could build a `Map<Integer, Mobile>` pretty easily. What have you tried? What would you expect to get if you provided a value of 350, for example? The value above or below?

Comment: What in case if there are few Mobile enums with same price? Is it even possible in your case?

Comment: If there are limited number of objects in the Enum then you can happily iterate all the `values()` to get the desired one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a *mapping* from the value to the enum instance. This will be a static variable that can (must) be filled by the constructor:

*(Code edited as per Pshemo's comment)*

```
enum Mobile {
    Samsung(400), Nokia(250),Motorola(325);

    private static final Map<Integer, Mobile> MOBILES = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (Mobile m : values())
            MOBILES.put(m.price, m);
    }

    int price;

    Mobile(int p) {
        price = p;
    }

    int showPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public static Mobile byValue(int value) {
        return MOBILES.get(value);
    }
}
```

Note that some autoboxing and -unboxing is involved. And consider throwing an IllegalArgumentException if the value is not existent.

An additional note: This requires all values to be distinct!

Comment: Ececuting `MOBILES.put(p, this);` in constructor is impossible here, because while initializing  enum values like `Samsung` static map `MOBILES` is not yet initialized. One of possible ways to solve it would be filling map with values after all enum fields are initialized, so maybe place code like `static { for (Mobile m : values()) MOBILES.put(m.price, m); }` after declaration of `MOBILES`.

Comment: tried both. I am getting an error as : Cannot refer to the static enum field Mobile.MOBILES within an initializer

Comment: @Pshemo You are right. So I changed the code and now it works correctly. @AnushreeAcharjee: Simply add a main method to this enum and run the statement `System.out.println(MOBILES)` in it. You will see, it works well.

Answer (score 5):

Create a static method in `Mobile` enum itself

```
public static Mobile getByPrice(int price) {
    for (Mobile mobile : Mobile.values()) { // iterate all the values of enum
        if (mobile.price==price) { // compare the price
            return mobile; // return it
        }
    }
    return null; 
    // either return null or throw IllegalArgumentException
    //throw new IllegalArgumentException("No mobile found in this price:"+price);
}
```

Comment: You may (or may not) depending upon circumstances prefer this to behave the same way as valueOf and throw a IllegalArgumentException rather than returning null when a value is not found but that is a choice for the implementer.

Comment: @Caleryn yes I strongly agree with you.

Comment: This is what I did when I had a similar requirement.